# Java Stream: return exclusive elements by comparing atrribute value from two collections

Tags: java, java-stream

Considering following POJO classes, please note all the attributes can be null and not wrapped by `Optional`

```
public class Food{

    String name;    // can be null
    Double weight;
    
    // gettes & setters & constructor
}

public class Drink{

    String name;    // can be null
    Long volume;
    
    // gettes & setters & constructor
}

public class Meal{
    Long id;
    Timetstamp date;
    List<Food> foodList;
    List<Drink> drinkList;
    
    // getters & setters
    // constructor
}
```

Now there are 2 Meals I'd like to find exclusive food and drink items

```
Meal lunch = new Meal();
Meal dinner = new Meal();

// .. skip logic to fill in attribute value for lunch & dinner

List<Food> uniqueFoodInLunchAndDinner = ....    // require implementation
List<Drink> uniqueDrinkInLunchAndDinner = ....  // require implementation
```

My question is how to implement above logic using less code but also not sacrifice performance.

Blow is my code but I think it's not good enough

```
List<Food> getUniqueFoodInLunchAndDinner(Meal lunch, Meal dinner){

    List<Food> missingFoodinDinner = lunch.getFood().stream.filter(Objects::nonNull).filter(foodInLunch -> {
        dinner.getFood().stream()
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .map(Food::getName)
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                        .contains(foodInLunch.getName()) == false).collect(Collectors.toList());
    })

    return dinner.getFood().addAll(missingFoodinDinner );

}

// same logic for drink...
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not good enough? Are you getting incorrect output? Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: @Jorn I tried to get better/cleaner code

Comment: If you are looking for improvements on working code, [codereview.se] is a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have too main `filters`, not sure if you really need them. I think you only need items where `foodInLunch.getName() == false` why don't you use

```
X.stream().map(Food::getName).collect(Collectors.toSet()).contains(foodInLunch.getName()) == false).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I think the above snippet should return the same result. You can pass `X` as a param. First case it would be food, and second it would be drink

Comment: thanks but what about the null situation like if `meal.getFoodList() == null` or `food.getName == null` or `meail.getFoodList().get(n)== null`

Comment: `Set` should do away with the null